# From numpy array, get indices of values list

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

like this:

```
>> arr = np.array([[0, 50], [100, 150], [200, 250]]) 
>>> values = [100, 200, 300] 

>>> arr in values
```

expect:

```
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]])
```

result:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I wrote following code and it works, but this code cannot accept changing length of list

```
(arr==values[0]) | (arr==values[1]) | (arr==values[2])
```

Comment: You are using the script or the command line?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin why does that make a difference

Comment: You can use `np.isin(arr,values)`

Comment: @BogdanDoicin This example is written as on command line for simplification, but I want to this code use on script. Any differences in this issue?

Comment: @BlueRineS Thanks. Can you write this as answer?

Comment: @MiyashitaYosuke can I write _what_ as an answer?

Comment: @BlueRineS please write `np.isin(arr,values)` , and I will accept it

Comment: @MiyashitaYosuke why me lol? And somebode already answered

Comment: @BlueRineS I did not notice plus's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use np.isin:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 50], [100, 150], [200, 250]])
values = [100, 200, 300]

np.isin(arr, values)
```

result:

```
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but only for 2 level depth:

```
import numpy as np


def is_in(arr, values):
    agg = []
    for a in arr:
        if isinstance(a, list):
            result = is_in(a, values)
            agg.append(result)
        else:
            result = np.isin(arr, values)
            return result
    return agg

arr = np.array([[0, 50], [100, 150], [200, 250]])
values = [100, 200, 300]

print(is_in(arr, values))
```

Answer (score -3):

also change name of that variable from values to something different to valuess for example.

```
if valuess in arr.values :
print(valuess)
```

OR

Use a lambda function.

Let's say you have an array:

```
nums = [0,1,5]
Check whether 5 is in nums:

(len(filter (lambda x : x == 5, nums)) > 0)
```

Comment: why change the variable name? Also, how does this answer the question..